# What is the right way to deal with terminated socket "client"

Tags: java, sockets

I have socket serve/client application. The "server" is waiting for data from "client", but if the client had been terminated the server throws `EOFException`.

Somewhere in the code in the server socket I have:

```
private ObjectInputStream in;
```

and somewhere I read the data:

```
in.readObject();
```

So should I just surround in.readObject(); in try-catch block or there is another solution?

Comment: Yes. Use `try-catch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the Javadoc API for ObjectInputStream.readObject, you'll see the list of exceptions

- ClassNotFoundException - Class of a serialized object cannot be
  found.
- InvalidClassException Something is wrong with a class used by
  serialization.
- StreamCorruptedException Control information in the stream is inconsistent.
- OptionalDataException Primitive data was found in the stream instead of objects.
- IOException - Any of the usual Input/Output related exceptions.

IOException (which 99% of the time is a SocketException (subclass of IOException) is special case where your Socket has shutdown, so you should process this as if you have lost connection.

All of the other exceptions however indicate that your client is sending you something you aren't expecting. You should catch each of these Exceptions by name and send back a message saying that they need to update the client software version to the version that your server is ready to communicate with. Flush that message out, and then probably best to close the socket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like following. `EOFException` is a direct subclass of `IOException`. You should also catch `IOException`.

```
try{
    ....
    in.readObject();
    ....
} catch(EOFException ex1){
    // eof exception is thrown
} catch(IOException ex2){
    // other types of IO exception is thrown
}
```